# MemoryStream error convert base64string to bitmapimage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to convert a base64string to Bitmapimage.
The below code is used in my windows phone project and it works fine, however I am reusing this code in my windows store app project and getting this error. I have no clue in fixing this error.

Error Msg:

> The best overloaded method match for 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSource(Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream)' has some invalid arguments
>
> cannot convert from 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream'

DATADB.cs

```
class DATADB
{
    public class NewsObject
    {
        BitmapImage thumb = null;
                
        public BitmapImage Thumb { 
            get {
                if (thumb==null)
                {
                    Regex rgx = new Regex("^[^,]*,");
                    thumb = Utilities.base64image(rgx.Replace(this.default_photo, ""));
                }
                return thumb;
            }
        }
        
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Utilities.cs

```
class Utilities
{
    public static BitmapImage base64image(string base64string)
    {
        if (base64string == "" || base64string == null) return null;

        byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms); //Getting error message here.
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` instead of `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

trying to use

```
bitmapImage.SetSource(new MemoryRandomAccessStream(ms));
```

instead of

```
bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
```